# Get a user's mailbox size within a date range

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, powershell-cmdlet

This is Exchange 2007.

We are attempting to determine how much disk space would be used if we did an export of user mailboxes within a certain date range.

I can use the Export-Mailbox cmdlet to export contents within a date range (startdate and enddate switches), but these switches do not exist with the Get-Mailboxstatistics cmdlet.

Ideally, the command would go something like this (obviously this is pseudo-code):

```
get-mailbox -organizationalunit "target" | get-mailboxstatistics -startdate "02/01/2012" -enddate "02/15/2012"
```

But, again, since those switches don't exist for the Get-Mailboxstatistics cmdlet, I'm not sure how to pull this off.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use the EWS managed API to create a search folder in each user's mailbox for all emails in the date range you're looking at.

Let the server chew on that for awhile.

Go back with EWS and read the size of that folder on each mailbox.